# What does "Now you see me, now you don't," mean, and where did it originate?

Tags: phrase-origin

In several works, I saw a character use the phrase "Now you see me, (beat) now you don't". I think I also remember a character using just "Now you see me" and then disappearing.

The Wikipedia disambiguation page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Now_You_See_Me, says that many works have adopted the phrase but doesn't say what it means or at least originally meant.

So,

- is there a known source that first use the phrase?
- what did it mean in the first sources that used it? it feels like it's become so common that some of the current uses are variations or subversions

Comment: As I said, before my comment was deleted by some idiot, the phrase "Now you see it, now you don't" is a long-standing idiom commonly used by "slight-of-hand" magicians, going back to the 1940s at least, and a common expression in magic acts on TV in the 1950s.  Twisting that to "Now you see me..." is not much of a stretch.  (It basically means what it says.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, the phrase is used to express that something is gone without clear explanation. You may be interested in reading about "[Abracadabra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abracadabra#History)" and its history, which is close to this phrase to some extend. The phrase also refers to someone making something (or themselves) go away magically, out of a sudden and without vivid explanation.

Comment: It is possible that the "now you see me" variant was used as a catch-phrase by some entertainer (or even a cheesy ad on TV), but if so, it never made it into the vernacular to any great extent.

Answer (score -3):

I have always thought it's a paraphrase of [John 16:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2016%3A16&version=NRSV):

> A little while, and you will no longer see me, and again a little
>   while, and you will see me.

But I can find no evidence to support it - other than not being the only one to make this connection:
http://celebrationpublications.org/blog/patmarrin/16/05/3489
https://vineyarddailyreflections.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/now-you-see-me-now-you-dont-john-16-16-20/
https://bible.org/seriespage/5-now-you-see-me-matthew-514-16
http://www.tenth.org/resource-library/sermons/now-you-see-me-now-you-don-t
http://subsplash.com/centerpoint/v/d4d7694